# Core only dumped upon receiving SIGQUIT

Tags: 13.04, signal, ulimit

Learning about signals, I found out that calling the `<stdlib.h>` function`abort(void);` in a C program, which roughly equals to raising a `SIGABRT` signal, doesn't create a `core` file on my Ubuntu 13.04 despite having set `ulimit -c` to `unlimited` and receiving a `core dumped` message.

Following the `signal(7)` manpage , I killed a running instance of `yes` with all the signals marked with the `Core` flag, whose default action is declared to be the termination of the process and dumping the core.

Out of all the signals mentioned (`SIGILL, SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGSYS, SIGTRAP, SIGXCPU, SIGXFSZ, SIGIOT, SIGQUIT`), however, only `SIGQUIT` caused the creation of a `core` file.

Is this documented and / or configurable behaviour, or is it a quirk?

Comment: A bit of introduction should be helpful in my opinion for someone who doesn't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Good thinking, I added an introduction.